# Xamarin archive build fails for ios adhoc distribution

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

So my ios project builds fine using ad-hoc|iphone configuration. I am able to run in debug mode against simulator. The problem i have is when i attempt to archive the project i get following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The OutputPath property is not set for project 'arnBooking.iOS.csproj'.  Please check to 
make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  
Configuration='Ad-Hoc'  Platform='iPhoneSimulator'.  This error may also appear if some other project 
is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or 
is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an  
equivalent Configuration or Platform.   arnBooking.iOS
```

[image]

I have looked in my project properties and debug is the only configuration that builds against iPhoneSimulator and the only configuration that has the simulator as its output path. I am trying to figure out why the archive builds agains different configuration than normal build.

Has anyone ran into this?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.5

Comment: `...Configuration='Ad-Hoc'  Platform='iPhoneSimulator'...` :  Not sure if that is bug or not, but what is your platform set to(?) as you can not build a release for the simulator.

Comment: @SushiHangover To clarify the build works fine. I only get this error why i do Build->Archive. The buld is set to adhoc|iphone

Comment: Strange as the error states `iPhoneSimulator` as the platform and thus the The `OutputPath property is not set for project` failure, have you checked if this is a known issue? FYI: build/archive is doing a complete build of the project (or trying to in this case)

Comment: Strange yes hence why i posed this question. I have checked but not finding any results

Comment: Can you please update your visual-studio and try again?

Comment: I updated visual studio and restarted machine. Still seeing issue however when i run from command line explicitly setting output path it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must have just been caused from visual studio cache or something. After cleaning, manually deleting bin and obj folders, and restarting my machine and mac it worked. Just Xamarin being its usual finicky self I suppose